# use variable part of ID with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of 8 divs: #video1, #video2, ... with each the same javascript actions to run when clicked, but with other id's (for #video1: show #image1, #preview1, ...).

Instead of writing 8 times the same code but with other id's, can I do this more efficient? Is it possible to take the sixth caracter (the number) from each #videoX as a variable when clicked, and use 
this in the code?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your event handler, you can extract the number, e.g. with a [regular expression *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var id = element.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
```

and then use it to create the IDs of the other elements:

```
var image_id = "image" + id,
    preview_id = "preview" + id;
```

Another option would be to assign [`data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to the elements and use them to store the numerical part of the ID.

Comment: +1 for the data attribute which is the only proper way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class name instead. This way it's independent of the IDs completely.

```
<div class="videoClick" id="...">...</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.videoClick').click(function() {
...
})
```

Comment: But I want them to run separately, not all at the same time.

Comment: They do run separately. The click handler responds to one particular click. You can determine which one was clicked inside the one function by looking at the element's ID.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can:

```
$("div[id*='video']").click(function() {
   var numid = $(this).attr("id").replace("video", "");
   alert(numid);
   //...use your numid value
});
```

Check [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ids = [#video1, #video2, #video3, #video4, #video5, #video6, #video7, #video8];

$(ids.join(",")).click(function(){
    var imageId = this.id.replace("video", "image");
    var previewId = this.id.replace("video", "preview");
    $("#"+imageId).show();
    $("#"+previewId).show();

});
```